# Не получается сделать кнопку, для того чтобы она забирала значение из строки entry значение

Tags: python, tkinter

Пытаюсь создать полушуточный вирус-вымогатель и у меня не получается сделать кнопку, для того чтобы она забирала значение из строки entry значение. В окне после нажатия на крестик появляется строка, но не появляется кнопка для того чтобы значение в этой строке как бы зафиксировать и записать для дальнейшего сравнения с 'ключём'.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


window = Tk()
window.title('Капутеру капут')
window.geometry('900x600')
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
window.config(bg='white')
text = Label(text='ё рот этого казино', fg='blue', bg='white', font=('Courier New', 34))
text.place(x=100, y=100, width=700, height=100)
count_text = Label(text='1', fg='blue', bg='white', font=('Courier New', 38))


def count_start():
    if int(count_text['text']) > 0:
        count_text['text'] = int(count_text['text']) - 1
        count_text.place(x=250, y=25, width=400, height=100)
        window.after(1000, count_start)
    else:
        count_text['text'] = 0
        width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
        height = window.winfo_screenheight()
        window.geometry(str(width) + 'x' + str(height))
        photo = PhotoImage(file="picture.gif")
        label = Label(image=photo, bg='white')
        label.image = photo
        label.place(width=width, height=height, x=0, y=0)

def keys():
    key = Entry.get()
    if key == 'КЛЮЧ':
        window.destroy()


def on_close():
    count_start()
    Entry().pack(anchor=NW, padx=8, pady=8)
    newtext = Label(text='Введите уникальный ключ-код иначе вирус ', fg='blue', bg='white', font=('Courier New', 14))
    newtext.place(x=100, y=200, width=700, height=100)
    newtext2 = Label(text='сотрёт вашу операционную систему через две минуты', fg='blue', bg='white', font=('Courier New', 14))
    newtext2.place(x=100, y=300, width=700, height=100)
    btn = ttk.Button(text="Ввести ключь", command=keys())
    btn.pack(anchor=NW, padx=8, pady=8)
    label = ttk.Label()
    label.pack(anchor=NW, padx=6, pady=6)

window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_close)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: а что именно не получается, е?

Comment: кнопка ввода не получается. её нет :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

надо указать в каком окне создаеться кнопка

```
btn = ttk.Button(window,text="Ввести ключь", command=keys)
```

тоесть первый аргумент функции это окно ткинтер в котором будет располагаться кнопка, а еще `keys()` в команде кнопки надо писать без () или не будет работать функция keys